# "Post your question" fails on Opera 10.10 Win XP SP3

Tags: support, stack-overflow, asking-questions, javascript, opera

I'm not able to submit a question using Opera 10.10 on Windows XP SP3.
I was logged in, every field was filled etc. No error messages were shown. After clicking the submit button, nothing happens.

After this I opened FF3, logged in to the site, copy-pasted all the form fields from Opera to FF, and clicked submit. This was successful.

It seems to me that the "Ask a question" page's javascript doesn't support Opera. Please fix this. Opera is the only browser that rocks.

(And now I just discovered that meta.stackoverflow.com has the same problem, as submitting this question with Opera was not possible and I had to do it with FF3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the site works fine with Opera 10.10.

In fact, I just asked a question on our dev instance fine from Opera 10.10.

I believe there are **some oddities with the way Opera handles the tags field**, and it is **specific to how a given user interacts with that field** (eg certain sequences of user actions in the tag field trigger it, but not others).

One of the many, *many* oddities of Opera. Same field presents no problems (for question submission, anyway) in Safari, Chrome, FF, IE, etcetera.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the tip. Must keep this in mind when I encounter weird problems with Opera. Is there any failsafe functionality you could implement to get around this? (And I still consider Opera to be THE browser =))

Comment: The failsafe way to use Opera with these sites is to be very careful how you type anything in the tags field. @kos

Comment: I experience the same problems when I ask or edit questions. As you wrote, I already suspected that this is a problem with the tags. I would be happy to have some failsafe functionality. For me, the submit button just gets gray - and I have to write the question/edit again. Maybe it could help to make the submit button working again after a few seconds. Normally the page of the new/edited question will be loaded - but just in case it does not work I'd have another try :)

Comment: It seems that pressing <Enter> in the tags-field is the thing disabling the post button

Comment: I'm not pressing <Enter> in the tags field and still run into this. Any other workarounds?

Comment: I'm having the same problem in Opera occasionally, but cannot find a reliable way to reproduce it... :(

Comment: Yeah, hangs indefinitely everytime I post a question on Opera 10.60 with Vista.  :-(  Have to boot up Firefox when I want to post a new question.

Comment: Same problem here, also Opera 10.60 on Vista

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: The work-around is to type the tags, then the body and finally the question. Since at least Opera 10.6, the "post" button is disabled if you fill the form in normal order, but it works if you fill it backwards.

Comment: Same problem here with all Opera 10.6x versions and 10.7x snapshots. I found that if I complete the tags field first, then edit the content of the question and finally the title, I can submit the question. However this may not work all the time.

What is strange is that I have this problem on Stackoverflow all the time, but I never got this problem on Superuser (yet).

I posted a bugreport on Opera, too.

Comment: Same problem here (ALWAYS), Opera 10.61 -- I click on submit, it gets disabled, and that's it. I am posting this way -- I fill all fields, then I open another tab, I enter SO --> ask a question, I fill all fields (ctrl+c, ctrl+v) but in reverse order. Then the question is posted.

Comment: This problem seems to have vanished with Opera 11 Build 1156, I can now post questions!  hurrah!