# "Post your question" just disables after clicking, not sending question

Tags: bug, opera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Post your question” fails on Opera 10.10 Win XP SP3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31801/post-your-question-fails-on-opera-10-10-win-xp-sp3)

"Post your question" just disables after clicking, not sending question.

Serverfault, Opera browser 10.10/win32

Even Now and here I have this issue... :(

It can be connected with TAGS auto-completion

Going Back and Forward DOES NOT help, it clears Title and tags////

Comment: I have no "Red" phrases about incorrect question, just disabling button after clicking it.

This issue leads me to enter a lot of copy-pasting of question and a lot of "Robot/Human checks".

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31801/post-your-question-fails-on-opera-10-10-win-xp-sp3

Comment: And how can I use the sites with Opera??

Comment: I love Opera, but I learned to use it "for most of sites", and simply switch to IE or Chrome if there is a problem with Opera. Remember that you use a browser which is a minority on the global usage. If there is a problem which happens only in Opera, don't expect every site maker to fix it, just switch when needed.

Comment: This is minority browser, but just search here for bugs with opera! It is often used by PC professionals.

I don't want to relogin into stackoverflow one more time when using "alternative", "non-minority" browser