# Is it possible to ask questions from Opera on MacOS X?

Tags: support, opera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Post your question” fails on Opera 10.10 Win XP SP3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31801/post-your-question-fails-on-opera-10-10-win-xp-sp3)

Post Your Question button grays out but nothing happens then.

Isn't it possible to use Opera 9.64 on MacOS X with Stack Overflow?

(I had to post this question with Safari.)

Comment: You have to be very careful how you interact with the "tags" field.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I highly recommend that you upgrade to Opera 10 (the current version as of this writing), as it fixes a lot of Opera bugs w/r/t the tags field.

Some people less charitable than myself might suggest that Opera itself is a bug. That's completely unfair. Opera does render *some* websites correctly!

Comment: about:blank is rendered perfectly.