# Unable to post questions through Opera

Tags: support, status-completed, opera

Unable to post questions through the latest version of Opera. Its quite frustrating, is this a known issue

Comment: Did you try to put tags both with pressing enter and clicking on them with mouse? It's a [known bug on this site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40248/when-will-opera-support-be-fixed-on-so) with all versions of Opera, it grays your "post your question" button.

Comment: No, it was not greyed out but the form didn't get submitted when you click it.

Comment: Same problem here: `Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.0; U; en) Presto/2.6.30 Version/10.61`.

Comment: Same problem 10.62 build 3500. It works sometimes but in 90% cases not.

Comment: Same problem... latest opera.

Comment: Its unbelievable that this problem is yet to be solved

Comment: Using 10.63 here, and it still doens't work :-(  I have to boot up chrome to post an answer, not the ideal solution!

Comment: If only there was a programming Q&A website where you could troubleshoot your jQuery problems...

Answer (score 1):

The "solution"/workaround to this is to not click the tags. Instead, just type them out, being careful not to create new tags. There is something funky going on when clicking the tags. It's not a perfect solution, but at least we can post.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to submit a question using Opera 10.60 on our development tier and this answer is being submitted with the same browser.

Were you logged into the site when you tried to post your question?

Comment: Perhaps he means the most recent development build.  In that case, however, the bug should be filed with the opera developers.

Comment: maybe it's related to the "good ol' bug" with Opera: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40248/when-will-opera-support-be-fixed-on-so

Comment: I was logged in when this happened and I have seen this issue even on older version of Opera 10.3x

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It occurs only when posting questions (not answers or anything else) and it only occurs when using Opera 10.70 snapshot. Opera 10.61 works fine, so I guess this is just a problem in the development snapshot.

Comment: Has a bug been logged with Opera Software?

Comment: Opera 10.70 is still beta, right?

Comment: @Piskvor: Yes, but now it's called Opera 11.

Comment: Yes. In early November, the latest version was Opera 10.70. Incidentally, the site works normally in Opera 11 for me.

Comment: Agreed, with Opera 11 I can finally submit questions!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using opera 10.61 and also having this problem.