# Not able to submit new question in Opera in ubuntu !

Tags: bug, status-completed, opera

I'm trying to ask a new question in stack-overflow through the Opera browser installed on my ubuntu 10.10. But I'm not able to press the submit button Opera. Everything works fine with firefox and IE browsers.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1097#1097

Answer (score 9):

Taking a look, there was some Opera-specific code in the tag plugin that suppressed submission when you press <kbd>enter</kbd>

```
// prevent form submit in opera when selecting with return key
$.browser.opera && $(input.form).bind("submit.autocomplete", function() {
    if (blockSubmit) {
        blockSubmit = false;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Apparently newer versions of Opera handle this differently.

I removed the opera "fix" but there is a side-effect; pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> will submit the form in most cases (unlike *all other browsers*). You will need to select autocomplete tags using your mouse and not the keyboard. Well, technically you can use <kbd>tab</kbd> then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> but that's a bit of a workaround.

Shrug. Such is the delightful, delightful world of Opera.

[image]

Comment: The only response ever I've received from Opera's officials was a threat to physically punch me in the face. I'm not even lying.

Comment: @esko see http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/3290996474 Opera is like the honors student who occasionally snaps and goes on a random killing spree. I'll take IE6 "special needs" over that any day

Comment: ...as opposed to virtually punched in the face?

Comment: Ah, this is the old cancelling keydown doesn't cancel keypress bug… If you just change the autocomplete to bind to keypress, it should work in Opera.